# How do you use FontAwsome Icons in Hyperstack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, isomorphic, hyperstack

What is the best way to use [FontAwsome](https://fontawesome.com) Icons in a [Hyperstack](https://hyperstack.org/) project with Rails and ReactJS, using Yarn to include just the icons you need?

Answer (score 1):

This is the best approach:

Add the modules with Yarn:

```
yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
yarn add @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
yarn add @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

Import them into one of your Webpacker packs:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faAngleDown, faAngleUp, faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

library.add(faAngleDown, faAngleUp, faCoffee);
global.Fa = FontAwesomeIcon;
```

Then use them in your components:

```rb
H1 { Fa(icon: 'coffee') } # to inherit your H1 style
Fa(icon: 'angle-down', size: 'xs) 
Fa(icon: 'angle-up', className: 'special')
```

If there are certain icons you are using often, you can add a helper method to your `HyperComponent` class:

```rb
class HyperComponent
  include Hyperstack::Component
  include Hyperstack::State::Observable

  def icon_check
    Fa(icon: 'check', className: 'green-color', size: 'lg')
  end
end
```

It really is that simple!